# Access Previous Month Query

Tags: database, ms-access

Creating a query to pull data from a previous month only from a table. No luck with any of my research but just trying to pull data based off of a month column only. The table includes the following fields:
Month, Type, Done and In Progress

Month field is listed January, March, etc.

Only trying to add a criteria in design view field. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Example

Table:[Month Done/IP and Sum]
Month     Type      Done    In Progress
Sept      1         10      2
Sept      2         3       0
Sept      3         11      6
Oct       1         1       1
Oct       2         6       7

After running query in this month (Oct) the results would be the following:
Month     Type      Done    In Progress
Sept      1         10      2
Sept      2         3       0
Sept      3         11      6

Answer (score 0):

It could be:

```sql
Select 
    *
From 
    YourTable
Where 
    MonthFromInvariant([Month]) = (Month(Date()) + 12 - 2) Mod 12 + 1;
```

using the functions:

```vb
' Returns the month number from the English month name.
' Abbreviated names are accepted.
' An ambigous abbreviation (i.e. "ju") will return the first match.
' Passing a non existing name or abbreviation will raise an error.
'
' For parsing localised month names, use function MonthValue.
'
' 2021-04-02. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function MonthFromInvariant( _
    ByVal MonthName As String) _
    As Integer

    Const FirstMonth    As Integer = MinMonthValue
    Const LastMonth     As Integer = MaxMonthValue
    
    Dim Month           As Integer
    
    MonthName = Trim(MonthName)
    If MonthName <> "" Then
        For Month = FirstMonth To LastMonth
            If InStr(1, MonthNameInvariant(Month, True), MonthName, vbTextCompare) = 1 Then
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End If
    If Month > LastMonth Then
        ' Month could not be found.
        Err.Raise DtError.dtTypeMismatch
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    MonthFromInvariant = Month

End Function



' Returns the English month name for the passed month number.
' Accepted numbers are 1 to 12. Other values will raise an error.
' If Abbreviate is True, the returned name is abbreviated.
'
' 2015-11-25. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function MonthNameInvariant( _
    ByVal Month As Long, _
    Optional ByVal Abbreviate As Boolean) _
    As String
    
    Const AbbreviatedLength As Integer = 3
    
    Dim MonthName( _
        MinMonthValue To _
        MaxMonthValue)      As String
    Dim Name                As String
    
    If Not IsMonth(Month) Then
        Err.Raise DtError.dtInvalidProcedureCallOrArgument
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    ' Non-localized (invariant) month names.
    MonthName(1) = "January"
    MonthName(2) = "February"
    MonthName(3) = "March"
    MonthName(4) = "April"
    MonthName(5) = "May"
    MonthName(6) = "June"
    MonthName(7) = "July"
    MonthName(8) = "August"
    MonthName(9) = "September"
    MonthName(10) = "October"
    MonthName(11) = "November"
    MonthName(12) = "December"
    
    If Abbreviate = True Then
        Name = Left(MonthName(Month), AbbreviatedLength)
    Else
        Name = MonthName(Month)
    End If
    
    MonthNameInvariant = Name

End Function
```

taken from module `DateText.bas` from my project [VBA.Date](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Date).

Comment: I'm sorry Gustav but this isn't with VBA and I don't have the experience with it. This is just simple Access 2016

Answer (score 0):

What about below query? It would better if you provide some sample data and expected output.

```
SELECT Month, Type, Done, InProgress
FROM Table3
WHERE (((Table3.Month)=Format$(DateSerial(Year(Date()),Month(Date())-1,Day(Date())),"mmmm")));
```

[image]

Comment: Harun24HR, I tried a version of your query and at least get some results finally.

Comment: SELECT [Month Done/IP and Sum].[Month #], [Month Done/IP and Sum].Month, [Month Done/IP and Sum].Type, [Month Done/IP and Sum].Done, [Month Done/IP and Sum].[In Progress]
FROM [Month Done/IP and Sum]
WHERE (([Month Done/IP and Sum].[Month #]=Month(Date()-1)));
The problem is I get results from this month only now vs either having no results or having every result. I'd want to pull results from only last month. Anything I'm missing or can adjust?

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it, Harun24HR thank you for your assistance. Was just needing a starting point. I needed to make another field with the months as numbers.

SQL Query pulling results I needed:
SELECT [Month Done/IP and Sum].Month, [Month Done/IP and Sum].Type, [Month Done/IP and Sum].Done, [Month Done/IP and Sum].[In Progress]
FROM [Month Done/IP and Sum]
WHERE ((([Month Done/IP and Sum].[Month #])=Month(Date())-"1"));

Comment: It would be better if you could explain the answer in detail for the future readers.